# css margin auto display inline-table

Tags: html, center, margin

I am trying to center a div (popup dialog) with css.
I would like to have a universal css declaration, and I'm nearly there.
The css I'm using works, but I have to explicitly define a width to de div.

## Demo

in following image the width of the popup is defined as 415px.

[image: IMG]

In following image the width is defined as AUTO.

[image: IMG]

When I look at the boxmodel in the downright corner, both are identical. My question is why is the last div wrapping to the left while it has a left margin?

I already tried all the display types. It seems the "table" and "inline-table" style are optimal for centering purpose.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/? You not providing us with your code doesn't really help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `margin: auto` only works with a defined `width`. Otherwise the browser doesn't know how to calculate the distance from each side. And yes an alternative to using `margin` would be to use `display: inline-block` and adding `text-align: center` to the parent.

Comment: That 'll explain it. But I think I'll stick with the defined width. Thanks for the help.